# probability question at college level , Ihave tried a method but not sure if its right

Tags: probability

Assume you roll $2$ dice and calculate the sum . Are the events 'the sum is at most $6$' and 'the sum is odd' independent. I'm thinking that $P(A\cap B)=P(A)\cdot P(B)$ . If its independent it should be $P(A\cap B)=P(A)⋅P(B)$.
$P(A\cap B)= 2/36 + 4/36 = 1/6$.
$p(A) = (1+2+3+4+5)/36= 15/36$.
$p(b) = (2+4+6+4+2+1)/36= 19/36$.

because $p(a) \cdot p(b) = 15/36 \cdot 19/36 = 95/432$. That means $1/6$ is not $95/432$ and the event is dependent. This is what have calculated I'm not sure if I'm doing this right

Comment: You have the right idea for showing in/dependence, but you made a mistake with computing $P(B)$; there are $18$ ways of getting an odd sum, not $19$.

Comment: 3: 2/36
5: 4/36
7: 6/36
9: 4/36
11: 2/36 . Im thinkin these sum are the only ones which is odd ones

Comment: Right, and your work above has an extra +1

Comment: is P(A) correct ?

Comment: The possible ways that two dice can land may be described by the 36 ordered pairs (i,j) where 1  ≤ i ≤ 6 and 1 ≤ j ≤ 6. These are equiprobable; each has probability = 1/36. To find the probability of, say, getting a 4 as the sum of the two dice you need to count how many ways i + j  =  4 among the 36 possibilities. If there are N ways in total, then the probability of a 4 on two dice is N/36.

Comment: Yes, $P(B)$ is the only mistake I see

Comment: Please use a more descriptive title in the future. The tag already tells us that this is a probability question. Imagine if everyone asked questions with such titles.

Comment: Titles usually start with a capital letter. "Ihave" needs a space. The word "not" should be preceded by "am". The contraction "its" needs an apostrophe. Questions that are so very sloppily written should be voted down and/or ignored.